# Spring framework compatibility with other spring projects

Tags: spring

We are trying to upgrade our repo with all latest spring project versions. For eg. we are planning to upgrade to spring code at 4.2 version. But we need information about its compatibility with spring boot or spring batch versions so we can upgrade them also to correct version.

Is there anyway to find the correct versions?

I know that spring provide bill of materials for modules like spring-jdbc, spring-websockets etc but I need info about compatibility between spring-xd and spring-batch with spring core framework.

Comment: Boot 1.3 is compatible with 4.2. check the pom of other dependencies

Comment: @user509755, Spring-boot has also come up with bill of materials,  when you read it's bill of materials POM file, you can come to know the compatible versions of corresponding springframework related jar files. And the best way is to run mvn dependency:tree command or you can use your IDE for the dependency test

Answer (score 0):

Start at the library with the most dependencies. Make a Maven `pom.xml` with Spring Boot declared as a dependency. Let Maven sort out the other dependencies. The display the result using [`dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html).

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

> Displays the dependency tree for this project.